# C++ abstract base class calling own pure virtual function results in "Undefined reference"

Tags: c++, function, virtual, abstract-class

I have a base class:

```
class Foo {
   public:
       virtual ~Foo() {}
       static void printFoos()
       {
           std::vector<Foo*>::iterator it;
           for(it=fooList.begin();it!=fooList.end();++it)
           {
               std::cout<<"Class: "<<(*it)->getClassName()<<"\n";
           }
       }
       virtual const char* getClassName()=0;
       static std::vector<Foo*> fooList;
};
```

And a few derived classes, example given:

```
class Bar : public Foo {
    public:
        Bar();
    private:
        const char* getClassName()
        {
            return "Bar";
        }
};
```

The above code gives "undefined reference to Foo::getClassName()" which Im assuming because the code wants to call Foo::getClassName(), but how do I get it to call the function like a virtual call normally? I.E. How do I get it to call Bar::getClassName() from inside Foo?

EDIT: Forgot inheritance thingy

Comment: Where is the calling code? Can you paste that?

Comment: Also Bar isn't deriving from Foo at least in your code above.

Comment: If you declare getClassName as public in the Base class, shouldn't it be public in the Derived class, as well?

Comment: Your code, after being suitably modified, doesn't give an error from `g++ -ansi -pedantic -Werror -Wall`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Not reproducible. http://ideone.com/h1uIl

Comment: Please create a simple, **complete** sample program that produces the error message you are seeing. Please post that complete program into your question. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: At least I know that it should work like this. I'm not having much luck figuring out what's causing the undefined reference since, in the example, it compiles fine. Thanks everyone, sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems `bar` does not inherit `foo`. You need to declare inheritance:

```
class bar: public foo { ...
```

Comment: Thats a typo. Sorry I typed up the example.

Comment: @Brian - you should always copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Items in `fooList` must be created with `new`, `fooList[0] = new Bar()`. And `Bar` must inherit from `Foo`, as WeaselFox said.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are undefined:

```
Bar::Bar() is undefined

-   Bar();
+   Bar() {}
```

and fooList is undefined:

```
+std::vector<Foo*> Foo::fooList;
```

Here is corrected program:

test.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
   public:
       virtual ~Foo() {}
       static void printFoos()
       {
           std::vector<Foo*>::iterator it;
           for(it=fooList.begin();it!=fooList.end();++it)
           {
               std::cout<<"Class: "<<(*it)->getClassName()<<"\n";
           }
       }
       virtual const char* getClassName()=0;
       static std::vector<Foo*> fooList;
};

std::vector<Foo*> Foo::fooList;

class Bar : public Foo {
    public:
        Bar() {};
    private:
        const char* getClassName()
        {
            return "Bar";
        }
};

int main()
{
    //intentionally leaked
    Foo::fooList.push_back(new Bar());
    Foo::fooList.push_back(new Bar());
    Foo::fooList.push_back(new Bar());

    Foo::printFoos();
}
```

output:

```
Class: Bar
Class: Bar
Class: Bar
```